# urllib2 gives inconsistent output - often part of the webpage is downloaded

Tags: python, curl, download, urllib2, urllib

I am using `urllib2` to open and save a webpage. However, often only a part of the webpage is downloaded, whereas sometime the full page is downloaded.

```
import urllib2
import time
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip

outFiles = ["outFile1.html", "outFile2.html", "outFile3.html", "outFile4.html"]

urls=["http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2011/sep/06/cameron-nhs-bill-parliament?commentpage=all",
"http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2011/sep/06/tory-scotland-conservative-murdo-fraser?commentpage=all",
"http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2011/sep/06/palestine-statehood-united-nations?commentpage=all",
"http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2011/sep/05/in-praise-of-understanding-riots?commentpage=all"]

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux x86_64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1'
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', user_agent)]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

for fileName, url in izip(outFiles,urls):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    responseBody = response.read()
    fp=open(fileName,'w')
    fp.write(responseBody)
    fp.close()
    time.sleep(np.random.randint(20,40))
```

Depending on different runs, the `outputFile.html` are of different size. Sometime the files are of size > 200Kb upto 1MB whereas some other time they are around 140KB. What can lead to this difference?

When the files are smaller the comment section is missing, however the file is never incomplete. Sometime the whole page including the comments are also download. I checked with `curl` and still had similar problem. What I don't understand is what can lead to this inconsistency.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Exactly what is in the 140 kB page? Does it just get cut off somewhere?

Comment: The comment section is cut off.

Comment: for me the size of file is `940KB` everytime.

Comment: @imsc If it's cut off at a specific place in the HTML, it sounds more like a rare bug in their CMS than anything that's `urllib`'s fault.

Comment: May be there is some problem with your connection because for me the `output.html` is same as `http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2011/feb/22/50p-tax-rate-treasury?commentpage=all`

Comment: Yes, it get cut off exactly at the same position, apart from the comment section everything else is there. What is CMS?

Comment: The partial file look something like this http://www.lce.hut.fi/~rajkp/outputFile1.html

Comment: I tried it using curl (without changing the User-Agent or any headers), I cannot reproduce this as everyone else in the comments are saying.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I only had problem when I download the files in a loop. Very weird!

Comment: I also experience this issue while crawling using threads. I have to redownload the page when I detect it is missing some part. I tried multiple libraries to fetch but still issue. I used urllibl,urllib2,urllib3, requests, HttpConnection. Any one has fixes?